# Unable to launch WebDriver Agent because of xcodebuild failure

Tags: android, ios, iphone, appium

[image: WebDriver Agent Build Failure]

Me using Xcode_8.2.1 . When i am building my app its trowing error implicit converstation from nullable pointer

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to

1. Get clean **WebDriverAgent** project from [github repo](https://github.com/appium/WebDriverAgent) or via appium installation, you can find it on your local machine:

`/Users/someName/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/WebDriverAgent`

2. Run `./Scripts/bootstrap.sh` for "clean" project in path specified above
3. Open `WebDriverAgent.xcodeproj` and check if there are any errors